# Which is the best way to implement enums in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, enums

I was thinking about a nice way to implement an enum-like structure in JavaScript. I came up with a few solutions but which one is the best to use?

static getter class:

```
class Enum {
    static get A() {
        return 0;
    }

    static get B() {
        return 1;
    }

    static get C() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

This can be used like `var a = Enum.A // a == 0`.

Online I found a solution using an object an freezing it:

```
const enum = {
    A: 0,
    B: 1,
    C: 2
}

Object.freeze(enum);
```

This can be used like `var b = enum.B // b = 1`.

I am wondering if one of this methods is better in performance and in memory usage?

Comment: There are additional approaches as well. The class-based approaches absolutely the worst possible option.

Comment: Questions that ask for the "best way" to do something can either get good answers, or fall into the "opinion based" trap. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use as below:

```
const Colors = Object.freeze({
    A: 0,
    B: 1,
    C: 2
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested both methods and the class method of implementing an Enum is really the worst.
So I will stick to freezing an Object.

The only case where the class method performed better was when using the enum at many different Spots in the code (in different modules usw...)

But thanks to everyone answering.

Answer (score -1):

You can use TypeScript:

```
enum MyEnum {
 A = 0,
 B = 1,
 C = 2
}
```

But if you need vanilla JS, here's code compiled by TS Compiler:

```
var MyEnum;
(function (MyEnum) {
    MyEnum[MyEnum["A"] = 0] = "A";
    MyEnum[MyEnum["B"] = 1] = "B";
    MyEnum[MyEnum["C"] = 2] = "C";
})(MyEnum || (MyEnum = {}));
```

Hope, this will help